# How to implement a PNG decoder completely from scratch

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, png, zlib, deflate

I started to work on a PNG encoding/decoding library for learning purposes so I want to implement every part of it by hand.

I got pretty long with it but now I'm a bit stuck. Here are the things I succesfully implemented already:

- I can load a PNG binary and go through its bytes
- I can read the signature and the IHDR chunk for metadata
- I can read the IDAT chunks and concatenate the image data into a buffer
- I can read and interpret the zlib headers from the above mentioned image data

And here is where I got stuck. I vaguely know the steps from here which are:

- Extract the zlib compressed data according to its headers
- Figure out the filtering methods used and "undo" them to get the raw data
- If everything went correctly, now I have raw RGB data in the form of `[<R of 1st pixel>, <G of 1st pixel>, <B of 1st pixel>, <R of 2nd pixel>, <G of 2nd pixel>, etc...]`

#### My questions are:

- Is there any easy-to-understand implementation (maybe with  examples) or guide on the zlib extraction as I found the official specifications hard to understand
- Can there be multiple filtering methods used in the same file? How to figure these out? How to figure out the "borders" of these differently filtered parts?
- Is my understanding of the how the final data will look like correct? What about the alpha channel or when a palette is used?

Comment: See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2083

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes. You can look at [puff.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/contrib/puff/puff.c), which is an inflate implementation written with the express purpose of being a guide to how to decode a deflate stream.
2. Each line of the image can use a different filter, which is specified in the first byte of the decompressed line.
3. Yes, if you get it all right, then you will have a sequence of pixels, where each pixel is a grayscale value, G, that with an alpha channel, GA, RGB (red-green-blue, in that order), or RGBA.